# Variable \"$file\" got invalid value

Tags: javascript, typescript, file-upload, graphql

I try to upload a file with GraphQL. While upload, I get following error message:

> Variable "$file" got invalid value { resolve: [function], reject:
> [function], promise: {}, file: { filename:
> "insung-yoon-TPvE8qPfMr0-unsplash.jpg", mimetype: "image/jpeg",
> encoding: "7bit", createReadStream: [function createReadStream] } };
> Upload value invalid.

The only solution I found, was to disable the upload at `apollo-graphql` and add `graphql-upload`

```js
new ApolloServer({ schema, context, uploads: false })
app.use(graphqlUploadExpress({ maxFileSize: 10000, maxFiles: 10 }))
```

I already had added this setting, but the issue is still there.

My mutation looks like:

```
@Mutation(() => ReturnType)
uploadFileAndData(
  @Ctx() ctx: Context,
  @Arg('data', { description: 'File Upload' }) data: MyInputType,
): Promise<ReturnType> {
  return functionWithMagic({ ctx, data })
}
```

and my InputType like:

```
import { FileUpload, GraphQLUpload } from 'graphql-upload'

...
@InputType({ description: 'Upload data input' })
export class MyInputType {
  @Field(() => GraphQLUpload)
  @Joiful.any()
  file: FileUpload
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching, I finally found my issue. We are using a mono repo, and had installed two different version of `file-upload` in two packages. When I changed the version, at both packages on the same version and the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

To add, if you're using Altair graphql client, this error can originate from the client itself.

try:
1- close all tabs and start altair again
2- redo step one, then close the query tab and rewrite the query.